# ASP - how to use ajax modal/telerik radwindow to update control on previous page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

The setup I have is very simple.

on `Details.aspx` i have a formview and a button.  When the button is clicked it opens up a telerik radwindow to `editdetails.aspx`.  On `editdetails.aspx` i have a button that says submit.  What I want to do is close the radwindow that was opened and then refresh only the formview on `details.aspx`.  Any help is welcomed!

`details.aspx`

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvDealershipInformation" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div>
            <h3>
                Dealership Information</h3>
        </div>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table id="tblDealershipInformation" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="formviewCommandRow">
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="EditFormViewButton" ImageUrl="~/secure/images/edit.jpg"
                        ToolTip="Edit Dealer Information"  OnClientClick="ShowEditDealerInformationForm(); return false;"/>
                </td>
                <td>
</table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

here is `ShowEditDealerInformationForm()`

```
function ShowEditDealerInformationForm() {
            var url = window.location.search;
            url = url.replace("?", ''); // remove the ?
            var oWnd = window.radopen("editdetails.aspx?" + url, "UserListDialog");
            oWnd.maximize();
        }
```

this opens up editdetails.aspx just fine, so on editdetails.aspx i have a button and that i want to close the radwindow and then update the formview on information.aspx

`editdetails.aspx`

```
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="UpdateContactInformation" Text="Submit" OnClick="RadButton_DealerContactRecord_Click"
        Skin="Web20">
    </telerik:RadButton>

    protected void RadButton_DealerContactRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "mykey", "CloseAndRebind('navigateToInserted');", true);

}

function CloseAndRebind(args) { 
    {
        GetRadWindow().close(); 
    }

    function GetRadWindow() {
        var oWindow = null;
        if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
        //Will work in Moz in all cases, including clasic dialog               
        else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; //IE (and Moz as well) 
        return oWindow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript alone can suffice for your update - examine this: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/dialogreturnvalue/defaultcs.aspx.

If you need to go to the server after the dialog page has updated something (e.g., database), examine this: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window. You will see that there are some additional JS functions you don't have. The vital one is on the main page that will trigger a partial postback to update the grid/formview.